# Display products under product header PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables; sublevel and subcat1. sublevel contains the products headers, or collective group name and the other one, subcat1 contains all the actual products..

Here is sublevel table;

`CategoryID SublevelID  Name
 
67         1          Anaesthsia Thermometers

67         2          Forehead Thermometers

67         3          Drug Testing Thermometers

67         4          Drug Testing Thermometers`

and here is the other table, subcat1;

`CategoryID SublevelID SubCatName

67         2          12 Level Thermometer

67         1          Clinitrend

67         2          Forehead Thermometer

67         3          Briteline

67         3          BriteEvent`

The idea of what i want is the output and when i mean output i mean in php code to be something like this;

**Anaesthesia Thermometers** - Clinitrend

**Forehead Thermometers** - 6 Event Disposable, 6 Event Reusable, 12 Event

**Drug Testing Thermometers** - Briteline, BriteEvent

The problem I keep running into is I keep repeating the same header with each product, but I only would like it once. I've tried GROUP BY, DISTINCT and LEFT JOIN but with every product that is retrieved it shows it's category header-I know I'm probably looking at the query the wrong way...everytime i think of something new that I could change the query I fail..

[I even drew out the table structure along with the ideal output](https://twitter.com/D_Azzopardi/status/258340698900819968/photo/1/large) to see it differently, but my brain doesn't work that way..

```
function catLevelsName(){

// This would be used to select which category $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];

global $dbc;

$query = "SELECT subcat1.SubCatName FROM subcat1 RIGHT JOIN sublevel ON sublevel.CategoryID = subcat1.CategoryID";  
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error(). "<p>with query;<br />$query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['Name'];
echo $row['SubCatName'];
}
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

ps. A million apologies for my formatting.

Answer (score 2):

*Short edit*, to answer your question: **you can't have**, as a sql query result, the sublevel label just one time, as it will be in each sql-join result row. I would suggest you to go deeper in joins theory and how sql itself provides output rows.

Well, i have two big doubts about your scenario:

1. I would have used more verbose names for tables
2. I have serious doubts about your database structure. Isn't subcat nested inside sublevel, in one-to-many relationship? In this case you should not have a category id in subcat table, and SublevelID should be the PK in Sublevel table.

Anyway, i assume you are bound to this structure, so i cloned it (without using keys/foreign keys, as your design is not really clear to me)

```
--
-- Table structure for table `SubCat`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SubCat` (
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SublevelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SubCatName` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `Url` varchar(127) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `SubCat`
--

INSERT INTO `SubCat` (`CategoryID`, `SublevelID`, `SubCatName`, `Url`) VALUES
(67, 2, '12 Level Thermometer', 'http://www.example.com/subcat-1'),
(67, 1, 'Clinitrend', 'http://www.example.com/subcat-2'),
(67, 2, 'Forehead Thermometer', 'http://www.example.com/subcat-3'),
(67, 3, 'Briteline', 'http://www.example.com/subcat-4'),
(67, 3, 'BriteEvent', 'http://www.example.com/subcat-5');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `SubLevel`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SubLevel` (
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SublevelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(127) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `SubLevel`
--

INSERT INTO `SubLevel` (`CategoryID`, `SublevelID`, `Name`) VALUES
(67, 1, 'Anaesthsia Thermometers'),
(67, 2, 'Forehead Thermometers'),
(67, 3, 'Drug Testing Thermometers'),
(67, 4, 'Drug Testing Thermometers');
```

PHP code for output display

```
<?php
// Weird database init
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'my awesome root password');
mysql_select_db('stack', $connection);
$result = mysql_query("select * from SubLevel s inner join SubCat c on s.SublevelID=c.SublevelID", $connection);
// Output array
$subLevels = array();
// Build our output array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $subLevelId = $row['SublevelID'];
  $subLevels[$subLevelId]['subLevelToDisplay'] = $row['Name'];
  $subLevels[$subLevelId]['subCats'][] = "<a href='{$row['SubCatName']}'>{$row['Url']}</a>";
}
// Format output
foreach ($subLevels as $id => $row) {
  print "{$row['subLevelToDisplay']} - " . implode(',', $row['subCats']) . "<br />";
}
```

This is my output:

```
Forehead Thermometers - 12 Level Thermometer,Forehead Thermometer
Anaesthsia Thermometers - Clinitrend
Drug Testing Thermometers - Briteline,BriteEvent
```

Hope this actually helps you, anyway i would re-think database layer in a more clear and 
structured way.

Comment: Hi @brazorf, Thanks for working within the structure of the 'database'. With your help the <a href="https://twitter.com/D_Azzopardi/status/262328594758524928/photo/1/large">current page looks like</a> how I would like it. I also figured that it would be the PHP code to help display what I wanted, but my skill level is still the foundation period. One thing I would like to ask with the implodes, now that I have each product can I user another implode or 'For each loop' to give each product their unique link (I will gather data from the database to build the url)? Thanks

Comment: Hey D_Azzopardi, link is not working. Provide me a correct link, or i can't get your point:)

Comment: Sorry about that @brazorf, here is the correct link. It's a static image, I hope this helps you understand my problem. https://twitter.com/D_Azzopardi/status/262328594758524928/photo/1/large

Comment: I've edited sql and php code to add product link. Is it this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Brazorf thanks for your continuos help on this..I haven't tried your coding yet. I may have complicated things as your previous code worked perfectly. The problem I had was wrapping the products with an anchor tag. When I meant get the url from a database I meant something like this product.php?category=forehead&sublevel=1 (that's just an example) I can build the link no problems, it was just dealing with the implode function as I couldn't put an anchor tag round each...it was more a PHP problem now rather then MySQL now..

Comment: Hi @Brazorf, I figured my head round how to wrap an anchor tag around each function. [code]$array_results[$row['Name']][] = '<a href="prod" title="">'.$row['SubCatName'].'</a>';[/code]. Stupidly I was trying to edit the inside the implode function. For now, I think you have cracked it for me. But what I will do now is to make the changes and then report back here.

Comment: Ok, anyway don't be scared about the use of implode. That's a pretty simple and useful function, take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this is what you're wanting, but here is the query I would recommend:

```
select sl.Name, sc.SubCatName from sublevel sl 
  join subcat1 sc 
    on sc.CategoryID=sl.CategoryID
    and sc.SublevelID=sl.SublevelID
  order by sl.Name;
```

This gives me the output from your sample data as follows:

```
'Anaesthsia Thermometers', 'Clinitrend'
'Drug Testing Thermometers', 'BriteEvent'
'Drug Testing Thermometers', 'Briteline'
'Forehead Thermometers', 'Forehead Thermometer'
'Forehead Thermometers', '12 Level Thermometer'
```

Once you have the query designed as you like, it's only a matter of reading the data with your PHP code and printing it in the format that you want.

Comment: Hi @Emo Mosley..When I was trying to figure it out, this query was similar to what I use. To be honest I went threw many similar versions. But I think it was the PHP code I really needed to display i how I wanted but I just didn't know what to write to get there..

Comment: @D_Azzopardi, I'm confused - are you looking for PHP code to build a web page like you [referenced here](https://twitter.com/D_Azzopardi/status/262328594758524928/photo/1/large)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dirty solution... :)

Using the reply from Emo Mosley... you could use arrays.

Example:

```
$array_results = array();
$query = "select sl.Name, sc.SubCatName from sublevel sl 
  join subcat1 sc 
    on sc.CategoryID=sl.CategoryID
    and sc.SublevelID=sl.SublevelID
  order by sl.Name;"
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error(). "<p>with query;<br />$query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $array_results[$row['Name']][] = $row['SubCatName'];
}
```

then:

```
foreach ($array_results as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo $key.": ".implode(", ", $value);
    }
}
```

Ive not tested it, but I think it should work :)

Comment: Hi Klian, why this is a dirty solution? Is the coding is verbose? This produces the results, so I'm heading in the right direction. Like I mentioned in my reply to @brazorf. The implode displays the products but they need to be a link to their product page, but my handling of this edit is poor. To make these become links would i need to put this through a 'for each loop' like; [code]$links = array();
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
    $links[] = "<a href='/page/results.php?r_category=". trim($value) ."'>". trim($value) ."</a>";
}
$links_str = implode(", ", $links);
echo $links_str;[/code]